# Firebase auth doesn't work in Gatsby V2 app deployed on Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, gatsby

In my Gatsby V2 web app, I am using firebase auth to login with google. It is working properly on my MacBook Pro but when I deploy to Firebase Hosting it doesn't work. Please see console logs in attached screenshot.[image: Console error]

I have already checked that the correct URLs are allowed for localhost and for deployed site for google login in Firebase admin panel. My guess is that it has something to do with gatsby-plugin-manifest or gatsby-plugin-offline. As per https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls , I added the whitelist url for gatsby-plugin-offline in the following way while keeping the existing whitelist url (as per https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-offline) :-

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
      options: {
        navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^[^?]*([^.?]{5}|\.html)(\?.*)?$/, /^(?!\/__).*/]
      }
}
```

I deployed the site again but it still didn't work.

**Steps to reproduce**

Deploy a GatsbyJS site on Firebase Hosting which makes use of Firebase Google Auth. The following plugins were used:-

```
plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-shopify`,
      options: {
        shopName: `...`,
        accessToken: `...`,
        verbose: true,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
        name: 'pages',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/asset/img`,
        name: `images`,
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/asset/font`,
        name: `fonts`,
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: '...',
        short_name: '...,
        start_url: '/',
        background_color: '#f2efec',
        theme_color: '#f2efec',
        display: 'minimal-ui',
        icon: '...'
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
      options: {
        navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^[^?]*([^.?]{5}|\.html)(\?.*)?$/, /^(?!\/__).*/]
      }
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms`,
    `gatsby-plugin-netlify`,
  ]
```

**Expected result** - On clicking Google Login Button, the popup should open asking for google credentials.

**Actual result** - The google login popup stays blank and then closes (with the console error seen above)

Comment: Removing gatsby-plugin-offline makes it work but ideally, I am looking for a solution which makes it work with the plugin.